# varchar to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I imported a CSV file with match statistics into my database in phpMyAdmin. One of these columns held the match date and time (called Match_date_time), formatted as 
`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

This was imported as a varchar, but when I try change it in phpMyAdmin to datetime with length/value of 19, I get an error `#1426 - Too big precision 19 specified for column 'Match_date_time'. Maximum is 6`

When I set it to 6, it comes out as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000000`

How can I change this column to the datetime type?

Comment: `alter table t modify column c datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision of date and time types in MySQL is not the total length of the formatted date. It's the precision of microseconds to store. `DATETIME(6)` means to store `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000000`. `DATETIME(0)` means to store no microseconds, `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

See [Fractional Seconds in Time Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html).

In general, there's little need to set column limits like `VARCHAR(100)`. They're a great way to unnecessarily hard code data limits. Most column types are variable size so you're not saving any space. Use the defaults and prefer unlimited, variable sized types like `TEXT` over `VARCHAR`.

But if you care about storing microseconds, you should specify it because MySQL (surprise, surprise) violates the standard. The default in MySQL is 0. The default in SQL standard is 6. If you don't care about microseconds, leave it be. It's a few bytes per column either way.

If the data in the varchar column is already in ISO 8601 format, and it sounds like it is, you can alter the column to be datetime.

```
alter table sometable
modify thatcolumn datetime
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Also thanks for the clarification on DATETIME precision